# MYSQL view conditional insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql view up and running.

```
concat(`dp`.`fld_name`,
            ' ',
            `mt`.`fld_model`,
            ' ',
            `m`.`fld_diameter_nominal`) AS `fld_meter_type_info`,
```

now what i want to do is basic if else statement.

```
if(fld_type == 1 || fld_type == 4 ) -> get rid of fld_diameter_nominal in concat
else -> same concat
```

How to put this in view?

EDIT: SOLVED

```
concat(dp.fld_name,
        ' ',
        mt.fld_model,
        ' ',
        case when `m`.`fld_type` in (1,4)
             then '' 
             else m.fld_diameter_nominal
        end
   ) AS fld_meter_type_info,
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
concat(dp.fld_name,
            ' ',
            mt.fld_model,
            ' ',
            case when fld_type in (1,4)
                 then '' 
                 else m.fld_diameter_nominal
            end
       ) AS fld_meter_type_info
```

Comment: Any chance you might insert an extra ")" in case? Because it gives syntax error

Comment: I removed one that was unnecessary

Comment: Error: There was an error while applying the SQL script to database. What is the problem I don't get it

Comment: @FreshPro: It should work. See [this simplified SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/21733)

Comment: Error 1052: Column 'fld_type' in the field list is ambiguos SQL Statement :/

Comment: AH ok Now I see, i need to use `m`.`fld_type` in if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
CASE WHEN fld_type in (1,4)
THEN oncat(`dp`.`fld_name`,' ',`mt`.`fld_model`)
ELSE
concat(`dp`.`fld_name`,' ', `mt`.`fld_model`,' ', `m`.`fld_diameter_nominal`) END AS `fld_meter_type_info`
```

Comment: @FreshPro: Forgot the `end` keyword, have updated the query kindly check